# Is likelihood ratio test the only way to build hypothesis tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

Usually we can construct likelihood ratio for testing the Null hypothesis and alternative hypothesis:  The likelihood ratio test $ P( l(\beta_{1}) / l(\beta_{2}) ) < \alpha $ is the rejecting region for the null hypothesis. Then the inequality would reduce to a formula with sufficient statistics as the variable.

My question is : is likelihood ratio test the only way to build up hypothesis test? If not, what would be the alternatives? If there are multiple alternative methods, when would likelihood ratio test be preferred ?

Comment: Try writing down the likelihood of a t-test.
(oops, was meant as comment, not answer). The point is: You can build hypothesis tests on asymptotics, ignoring the likelihood principle. Thus the answer to the initial question is no.

Comment: One common alternative is [permutation tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_%28statistics%29#Permutation_tests) (/randomization tests). These are not based on likelihood at all; an example is the Fisher exact test. Most goodness of fit tests are not based on likelihood considerations. An example is the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test). In general all you need is a statistic which tends to have a different distribution under the alternative (even if that's just 'not H0') than it does under the null. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... You don't need even to be able to compute that distribution under the null, if you can simulate it. This leaves you with the opportunity to invent statistics with the properties you want in very specific situations. When their assumptions hold, LR tests tend to have desirable properties that make them worth knowing about.

Comment: @joint_p a t-test can be derived from the test statistic in a Gaussian mean-shift LR test. You might like to consider the [one-sample situation](http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/ttest.pdf), and look at the rejection rule in an LR test; it results in rejection rule that corresponds to a t-test.

Comment: @Glen_b: Interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the likelihood ratio is not the only way to construct hypothesis tests, but it often is optimal.

In one flavour of the frequentist paradigm you can construct a hypothesis test from any arbitrary test statistic that can generate a p value ie a probability of observing the data, given the null hypothesis.  An alternative hypothesis does not need to be formally stated (other than "not null") and hence a likelihood ratio cannot be constructed.

Even when we do have a formal alternative hypothesis there are multiple ways of constructing tests, but the Neyman-Pearson lemma shows that in many situations the likelihood ratio will be the most powerful.  We are often seeking the most powerful test; or the "uniformly most powerful test" if the alternative hypothesis is composite (eg takes in multiple possible parameter values); or uniformly most powerful unbiased test if there is no clear uniformly most powerful.  So we often end up with a likelihood ratio test.

There are situations where likelihoods simply don't work - no density exists in the model for example.

The Bayesian paradigm gives an entirely different approach again, usually involving the calculation of a "Bayes factor" rather than a likelihood ratio.

Comment: Thank you very much fo ryour explanation Peter.  For you comment "There are situations where likelihoods simply don't work - no density exists in the model for example.",  I wonder if the hypothesis for uniform distribution on [a,b0] vs [a,b1] would be an example, since the likelihood ratio doesn't depend on sample Xi ?